# Why is the following code in Python about subclasses throw an error?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

I am a beginner in Python and have been coding along with a youtube video about classes, inheritance and subclasses. However, when I typed the following code and ran it, it threw and error even though my code has been identical to the instructor in the youtube. Can someone help me understand what is wrong with the code? (Both a picture of the code and the error is shown below)

(the link to the youtube video I watched is - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RSl87lqOXDE&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc&index=4)

[image: Code I ran]

[image: Error I got]

Comment: Please post codes as **TEXT**, to make it easier for people to copy-paste code into their own editors and reproduce the problem.

Comment: The reason is probably because you have a typo: `__inti__`. That `__inti__` method is never call (try putting a `print` inside it). What's called instead is the base class' `__init__` which expects 4 arguments (self, first, last, pay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you have a typo in the `Developer` `__init__` function. You have spelled it `__inti__`

That explains why it is asking for a different number of arguments. It can't find an `__init__` function for `Developer` so it is using the `Employee`'s `__init__`.